# sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)?

Tags: macos, mac, django, paypal

this is my code:

```
def test(request):
paypalrestsdk.configure({
  "mode": "security-test-sandbox",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"  })

payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [{
      "credit_card": {
        "type": "visa",
        "number": "4417119669820331",
        "expire_month": "11",
        "expire_year": "2018",
        "cvv2": "874",
        "first_name": "Joe",
        "last_name": "Shopper" }}]},
  "transactions": [{
    "item_list": {
      "items": [{
        "name": "item",
        "sku": "item",
        "price": "1.00",
        "currency": "USD",
        "quantity": 1 }]},
    "amount": {
      "total": "1.00",
      "currency": "USD" },
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

if payment.create():
  print("Payment created successfully")
else:
  print(payment.error)
return render(request, "test.html")
```

When performing the command payment.create () then it error : [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590) . I'm using Mac . please tell me why?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and this is what I found and how I fixed:

The Python version provided by Apple is out of date in regards to openssl. You can test your version by going into terminal:

```
python
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Above is the bad version. One fix is to install a new version of python. The easiest way is probably to use home brew as [described here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#certificate-validation-and-mac-os-x).

Below is similar to what you should see with an upgraded version of python. Then the paypalrestsdk will work.

```
python
>>> import ssl
>>> print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

Comment: The link about using home brew to install a new version of OpenSSL points to an article which links to this one: https://hynek.me/articles/apple-openssl-verification-surprises/, and the command is simply `brew install openssl`. However that won't necessarily change the version that Python uses.